# Prevent clicks on view that presented another view via UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a view that is presenting another view via

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[weakSelf presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

The only problem is that the "main" view that presented that new view, has buttons that can be touched because the ModalPresentationFormSheet doesn't take the full screen. I would like to keep that format, but prevent clicks while the Modal is being presented. I know I could do this this check on every possible buttons, but I am sure there is another way!

```
    if (![weakSelf presentedViewController])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just disable the user interaction on weakSelf.view when you present another view and then enable it once you dismiss the presented view? This should do the trick I guess.

Comment: Have you actually tried to touch these buttons? When you present a modal view controller as a form sheet, the presenting view controller's view is darkened , and its interface is automatically disabled (at least when I tried it).

Comment: You are right, but for some reason, it is not in this case. The background is in fact not darkened, and I can access the buttons in the back. Any ideas as to why? I am launching it from a block with QuickDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the "new view" as a child view of another view that has full screen and make that "parent view" background color to clear color so you can see the "main view" also.
 Now you can't click the button cause you are actually clicking the view that is the parent on "new view"

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to place an invisible 'shield' above the hosting view controller, but below the form sheet.

Basically, create an empty UIView whose background color is clear. Add that as a subview to your presenting view controller just before you make your call:

```
[weakSelf presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Now, this doesn't necessarily mean such a solution is in good taste. That is, the form sheet style isn't meant to be exclusive in that way, and it can be confusing if the UIView installed above is clear. So, you could reduce the alpha value on that view to turn it into a dimming screen, to help the user understand that the form sheet is the only thing they can interact with at that time:

```
UIView *dimmingScreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
dimmingScreen.alpha = 0.5; // play with this value to get different degrees of dimming
dimmingScreen.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // play with different colors
[self.view addSubview:dimmingScreen]; 

// Now present your form sheet, as you were:
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[weakSelf presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

You'll want to be able to remove the dimming screen too, so best make it a view controller property you can access so as to remove when needed.